# Illegal assignment from List<Set<Id>> to Set<Id>

Tags: apex, list, map, set

I have two maps like below:

```
Map<String,Set<Id>> emailMatchingContacts = new Map<String,Set<Id>>();
Map<String,Set<Id>> epostMatchingContacts = new Map<String,Set<Id>>();
```

I've loaded some keys and values to the maps. Now I'm trying to get all the contact id's added in this maps. Tried with minimum possible code like below

```
Set<Id> matchingContactIds = new Set<Id>();
matchingContactIds.addAll(emailMatchingContacts.values());
matchingContactIds.addAll(epostMatchingContacts.values());
```

but it was throwing an error like below

```
Illegal assignment from List<Set<Id>> to Set<Id>
```

Is that apex standard behavior, loading the map values into List by default?

Comment: Error states, you would need to iterate over map to add set from each value

Comment: When in doubt, I'd recommend consulting the documentation as a first step.

Answer (score 6):

`emailMatchingContacts.values()` will return **List of the values of Map from key-value pairs**. That will be `List<Set<Id>>`

This will be resolved by either 1 of them:

- emailMatchingContacts should be of type `Map<String,Id>` OR .
- you should do `matchingContactIds.addAll(emailMatchingContacts.get(key))`

`emailMatchingContacts.get(key)` will return `Set<Id>` from a given item which has key as `key`. PFB:

```
for(String key : emailMatchingContacts.keySet()) {
    matchingContactIds.addAll(emailMatchingContacts.get(key));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing the same now.

Comment: You can just loop over `values()` since you don't actually care about the key.

Answer (score 1):

[Map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm)'s `values()` method will give you the `List<Values>` which in your case is `Set<Id>`. So, when you do `emailMatchingContacts.values()`, you will get `List<Set<Id>>`.

And [Set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm)'s `addAll` method takes input as `List<elements>` or `Set<elements>`and not `List<Set<elements>>`

So, best possible way I can think of achieving your requirement is by iterating over the `values` and adding all the elements one by one.

```
for(Set<Id> ids : emailMatchingContacts.values()){
    matchingContactIds.addAll(ids);
}
```